# Ruby's hashie/Mash equivalent in Java

Tags: java, ruby

Which library or collection in Java should be equivalent to Ruby's [hashie/Mash](http://rubydoc.info/github/intridea/hashie/master/Hashie/Mash) ?

Comment: "Groovy" or "JRuby". In other words, you can't arbitrarily add methods/properties to Java objects at runtime.

Comment: Thanks folks. JRuby is what I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can do the same in Java, because of compile-time checks. But JRuby is very robust, and you can call it easily from Java, if you can't simply write Ruby code and run it under JRuby.